# Printing UITextField input to console

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to print my input from textfields I have setup to the console before I print them to a label. I've tried string interpolation and various other methods, but I can't seem to get it to print the inputs themselves. I know force unwrapping is frowned upon but I will handle it properly after I get this to work. I've checked other asks extensively but found nothing specific to this in particular

To be clearer, when I press submit I want the text from the textfields to print to the console. Right now what happens is the values only show up at (UITextfield)

```
class SPProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var typeOfCompany: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellPhone: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        typeOfCompany.delegate = self
        firstName.delegate = self
        lastName.delegate = self
        email.delegate = self
        cellPhone.delegate = self

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        cellPhone.resignFirstResponder()
    }



    @IBAction func onSubmit(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print(self.typeOfCompany.text!)
        print(self.firstName.text!)
        print(self.lastName.text!)
        print(self.email.text!)
        print(self.cellPhone.text!)
    }


}


extension SPProfileViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you want to display the value of textField in the Console, right? You can active the Console by selecting View > Debug Area > Active Console

Comment: It is active, i included a picture at the bottom of what shows now. What I want is to get the values and not (UiTextfield!)

Comment: What textField is connected with `onSubmit(_:)`?

Comment: I changed it to textfield after I wasnt getting anything fro it being Any. I noticed responses to similar issues in other questions has the sender as TextField. do I have it set up wrong?

Comment: I don't know when the `onSubmit(_:)` will be called

Comment: should I move it further up? Will that make it so the values themselves show?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the UI?

Comment: I included the screenshot

Comment: Yes, I see. Let change to this `@IBAction func onSubmit(_ sender: Any) {` and connect this method with the Submit button in the storyboard. It's working for me (just created a demo from your code).

Comment: I had it working the whole time i just didnt see the output to the right. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are watching variables view, Click on "show the console" icon at bottom right corner to view console area.
2. If that is not your problem than make sure IBAction onSubmit is connected to storyboard.